# Stripping HTML in SOLR for storage, not indexing

Tags: indexing, solr, filtering

I have managed to strip HTML from content when indexing data in SOLR.

But is it possible to strip HTML from data when simply storing data?

This is my field:

```
<field name="Content" type="textNoHTML" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And, the field type "textNoHTML" implements the solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory:

```
<charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory" />
```

As I said, this works fine for indexing, but is it possible to apply a similar filter for storing?

cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the DataImportHandler you can use the [HTMLStripTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#HTMLStripTransformer).

Otherwise, you'll have to implement this client-side on your own. If your client is .NET you could use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/).

Comment: +1 I see. So, if I'm importing data from a data store using the DataImportHandler, I can use that transformer... but if I'm adding via the XML commands, i can't? Why's that? Anyways, cool, I'll check out the agilitypack. cheers!

Comment: AFAIK stored fields are always stored verbatim. The DIH acts as a client so it can have transformers.